# Can I add time stamp to pdf using Apache fop XSL-FO

Tags: java, timestamp, pdf-generation, apache-fop

Is there any way to add time stamp for pdf using apache fop.

I am generating pdf like this:

```
    final File xsltFile = new File("D:\\test.xsl");
    final StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File("D:\\test.xml"));
    final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
    final FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

    final OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream("D:\\test.pdf");

    try {
        final Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

        final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));

        final Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/metadata.html

Comment: A timestamp or any custom information is nothing more than a parameter into the transform. Show some code as to how you are calling the product and someone can help you pass in the parameter you need.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
final FOUserAgent   foUserAgent  = FOP_FACTORY.newFOUserAgent();
/**/                foUserAgent.setProducer        ("Pro Ducer");
/**/                foUserAgent.setCreationDate    (new Date());
/**/                foUserAgent.setTargetResolution(300 /* dpi */);
```